# Как сортировать структуры используя qsort?

Tags: c++, массивы, struct, qsort

Мне нужно написать программу которая принимает данные студентов и их оценок по трем предметам. И затем используя qsort отсортировать их по сумме оценок за три предмета. Если сумма 2-х учеников одинаковая, то оставить их в том же порядке. Прошу Вас, помоогите разобраться с qsort. Заранее благодарю!

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    string name;
    int Chinese;
    int Math;
    int English;
}Student;

    int compare(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
        int s1=p1->Chinese+p1->Math+p1->English;
        int s2=p2->Chinese+p2->Math+p2->English;
        return s1-s2;

}

int main() {
    int NumberOfStudents;
    cin>>NumberOfStudents;
    Student students[NumberOfStudents]; 
    for(int i=0;i<NumberOfStudents;i++){
        cin>>students[i].name>>students[i].Chinese>>students[i].Math>>students[i].English;}
    qsort(*students, NumberOfStudents, sizeof(*students), compare);

    // TODO: print result

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код в вопросе нужно приводить в виде текста, а не скриншота. Отредактируйте вопрос (для этого нажмите "править" под вопросом) и добавьте код текстом.

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. `p1` и `p2` - указатели на структуру, то обращение к её компонентам будет осуществляться через `->`. Также следует выполнить приведение указателя `void*` к конкретному типу указателя на структуру `Student*`:

```
int comp(const void* p1, const void* p2){
        int s1 = ((Student*)p1)->Chinese + ((Student*)p1)->Math + ((Student*)p1)->English;
        int s2 = ((Student*)p2)->Chinese + ((Student*)p2)->Math + ((Student*)p2)->English;
        return s1 - s2;
    }
```

В функции `qsort` первым параметром передаётся ссылка на массив (`students`), а не первый его элемент. Третьим параметром является размер передаваемых элементов массива (в данном случае структуры) - `sizeof(*students)` или `sizeof(Student)`. [Информация](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/qsort) о функции быстрой сортировки.

В начале главного файла вы создаёте статический массив, количество элементов которого принимаете из потока ввода. Лучше создать динамический массив и освободить память после его использования.

```
Student *students = new Student[NumberOfStudents]; //выделение памяти
//программа
delete [] students; //освобождение памяти
```

Помимо `qsort` в библиотеке `<algorithm>` описана другая функция сортировки `sort`,которая позволяет сортировать STL контейнеры и массивы:

```
sort(students, students + NumberOfStudents, 
    [](const Student &p1, const Student &p2){
        int s1 = p1.Chinese + p1.Math + p1. English;
        int s2 = p2.Chinese + p2.Math + p2. English;
        return s1 > s2; //сравнение
    });
```

Подробнее о функции `sort` [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Comment: К сожалению выдает ошибку "const coid* is not a pointer-to-object type

Comment: Можете в виде текста предоставить код ?

Comment: Изменил, дико извиняюсь

Comment: @ZhohangirB, попробуйте использовать функцию sort для сортировки.

Comment: *"Лучше создать динамический массив и освободить память после его использования."* Или еще лучше - взять `std::vector`.